# Why is the macro-average PR curve not implemented in Scikit-Learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, precision-recall, scikit-plot

For multiclass classification, the PR curves in the scikit-learn example ([PR curve example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html#plot-precision-recall-curve-for-each-class-and-iso-f1-curves)) and the function to plot PR curves with scikit-plot ([API Reference](https://scikit-plot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/metrics.html#scikitplot.metrics.plot_precision_recall)) both only implement the micro-average PR curve. While the corresponding example and function for the ROC curves implements the micro-average and macro-average curve.

Is there a reason that the macro-average PR curve is not implemented?